# Improve output format of caught exception, using Write-Error

Tags: powershell, exception

say I have the following script `test-exception.ps1`

```
[CmdletBinding()]
    param()

process {
    1/0
}
```

if I run it, I get

```
Tentative de division par zéro.
Au caractère U:\test-exception.ps1:5 : 2
+     1/0
+     ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

if now I try/catch the error,

```
[CmdletBinding()]
    param()

process {
    try {
        1/0
    } catch {
        write-error $_
    }
}
```

I get

```
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ U:\test-exception.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,test-exception.ps1
```

where I lose the line number and the line text. I tried many variants but the only way I've found to get the first error message in the error stream of a surrounding CMD while try/catching the code (I want to be able to exit with some custom exit code, not 1) is

```
[CmdletBinding()]
    param()

process {
    try {
        1/0
    } catch {
        [Console]::Error.WriteLine(($_ | Out-String))
        exit 99
    }
}
```

did I miss something or is this the only solution?

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed, when you call `Write-Error` in a `catch` block, the error message only shows the origin of the `Write-Error` call, not the origin of the exception.

You could get the origin of the exception from the [`PositionMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.positionmessage?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0) property of  [`ErrorRecord.InvocationInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord.invocationinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0), but a far easier way is to just pipe the `ErrorRecord` object (`$_`) to `Out-String`.

In addition you may show the script stack trace by querying the [`ErrorRecord.ScriptStackTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord.scriptstacktrace?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0) property, which contains the chain of function calls that led to the error.

Finally, set the [`ErrorRecord.ErrorDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord.errordetails?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) property to override the default error message so all the information about the original error will be shown.

```sh
try {
    1/0
} catch {
    $_.ErrorDetails = ($_ | Out-String) +
                      "`n------- SCRIPT STACKTRACE -------`n$($_.ScriptStackTrace)" +
                      "`n `n------- CAUGHT AT -------"
    Write-Error $_
}
```

**Output:**

```text
C:\Test\ExceptionTest.ps1 : Attempted to divide by zero.
In C:\Test\ExceptionTest.ps1:4 Char:2
+     1/0
+     ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
 
------- SCRIPT STACKTRACE -------
at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Test\ExceptionTest.ps1: Line 4
at <ScriptBlock>, <no file>: Line 1
 
------- CAUGHT AT -------
In Line:1 Char:1
+ . 'C:\Test\ExceptionTest.ps1'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,ExceptionTest.ps1
```

The information shown after the "CAUGHT AT" line is still pretty useless, but I don't think we can do anything about that, as it is added automatically by PowerShell. At least the relevant information is shown at the top now.